# Find the center of a set of graphics

Tags: c#, graphics

I have a form with a panel where a set of complex graphics are painted (represented by blue circles in the image):

[image]

The graphics are painted using `DrawLine` and `DrawEllipse` methods of the `Graphics` class.

**I need to find the global center of the set of graphics** (yellow point on the image) so that I can apply some transformations afterwards, like centering the set of graphics on the panel.

The most direct workaround I can think of is finding the boundaries of the graphics, so they are contained in a rectangular frame (red box on the image) and then divide the frame's width and height by two.

But how can I achieve this? **Is there a method** that would allow me to find the top, bottom, left and right boundaries of the entire set of graphics?

Comment: Use [GraphicsPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath(v=vs.110).aspx) and [GraphicsPath.GetBounds()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/865tf5y6(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Idle has got it: __In addition__ to drawing them also add them to a Graphicspath and use its bounds

Comment: Thanks Idle_Mind for providing the solution and TaW for the instructions. I would like to mark down this question as answered. Please feel free to answer it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any method in `Graphics` to do what you're looking for, but rolling your own should be relatively easy assuming you know the dimensions of each component image. The various `DrawEllipse` methods each take a bounding rectangle in some form, so you've already got all of the information that you need.

The most straightforward approach would be to simply keep track of the farthest left, right, top, and bottom bound of each image as you draw it and then form the complete bounding rectangle from those dimensions. You'll also need to account for the width of the `Pen` that you're using to draw your images.

As an alternative, you might want to take a look at the [`GraphicsPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/865tf5y6(v=vs.110).aspx) class. [`GraphicsPath.GetBounds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/865tf5y6(v=vs.110).aspx) would more or less give you what you're looking for. If `GraphicsPath` doesn't work for you, then I think you're probably stuck writing your own code.

Comment: Indeed, I used `GraphicsPath` and `GraphicsPath.GetBounds()` as you and Idle_Mind suggested. Worked perfectly, no need to work out any complex algorythm.

Comment: _The various DrawEllipse methods each take a bounding rectangle in some form, so you've already got all of the information that you need._ - While that is true for DrawEllipse it isn't for DrawCurves, which can seriously overdraw the point array..